# Adding or Removing a level to a TreeNode

Tags: winforms, treeview, treenode

I was wondering if it was possible with a TreeView in a windows form to add or remove a level?

For example:
my treeview is like this to begin with:

```
ParentNode  
|    Child1  
|    Child2
```

if user clicks on a button to add a level to Child2 it becomes:

```
ParentNode   
|    Child1  
|    |    Child1.1
```

There is a a `Node.Level` function but only usable to get the level and not to set it.

EDIT:
The nodes are built automatically, the level is assigned depending on the style of an excel cell. The problem is, it happens that the created node is not at it's correct place because the excel file is not well made. So I see 2 options o resolve this problem:

1- the user modifies the excel file directly
2- I create a `Move Left` `Move Right` button on a selection of nodes.

I'd like to offer the 2nd possibility.

Here's the code I used to build the nodes:

```
public static void AddNodes(Excel.Application app,
                                    TreeView treeView)
    {
        Excel.Range selection = app.Selection;

        ArrayList style = new ArrayList();

        TreeNode parentNode = treeView.SelectedNode;

        //Selected Node => Last used node
        for (int i = 1; i <= selection.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeNode tn;

            int fontSize = Convert.ToInt32(selection.Cells[i].Font.Size);

            if (!style.Contains(fontSize))
            { 
                style.Add(fontSize); 
            }

            else if (style[style.Count - 1].Equals(fontSize))
            {
                try
                { 
                    treeView.SelectedNode = treeView.SelectedNode.Parent; 
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                { 
                    ErrorBox(x); 
                }
            }

            else
            {
                int indexPreviousCellofSameColor = style.IndexOf(fontSize);

                //Select TN parent
                for (int j = 1; j <= (style.Count - indexPreviousCellofSameFont); j++)
                { treeView.SelectedNode = treeView.SelectedNode.Parent; }

                style.RemoveRange(indexPreviousCellofSameFont + 1, style.Count - indexPreviousCellofSameFont - 1);
            }

            if (selection.Cells[i].Value2 == null)
            {
                //if empty cell, do something ... or nothing
                treeView.SelectedNode = treeView.SelectedNode.LastNode;
            }
            else
            {
                //Add new TN to parent - TN object corresponds to excel cell
                tn = new TreeNode()
                {
                    Text = selection.Cells[i].Value2,
                    Tag = selection.Cells[i],
                };
                treeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(tn);
                tn.ToolTipText = tn.Level.ToString();

                //selected TN => created TN
                treeView.SelectedNode = tn;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It entirely depends on how you added the nodes, nothing else.

Comment: @HansPassant would you like me to add the code of how i build the nodes? Honestly, I don't see how that can influence moving the node to the left or right.

Comment: I dont get the problem. When adding a node to a treeview one has to enter the parent node as parameter, which in your example will be Child1 So what is the problem you are experiencing ?

Comment: @GuidoG please see Edit. I provided some context and the way I'm building the nodes, and more precisely the why I'm trying to achieve this

Comment: so you want a button right, and when clicking on it, the selected node in the treeview should become a new level for the node just above it ? something like that ?

Comment: @GuidoG yes absolutely.

Comment: what if you select Child1 in your example and than click on the button move-right ?

Comment: @ that would not be possible, as there can not be a difference of 2 levels between two consecutive nodes. Some controls would be added to make sure the user cannot perform this action

Comment: @ElliottAddi See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change my answer completely to the changed question.
This seems to do the job in my tests. It moves the selected node to a new level, under the one that was just above it.
It needs more checks offcourse to make sure your not moving nodes to oblivion...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode selected = treeViewFilter.SelectedNode;
    TreeNode parent = selected.Parent;

    // find the node just above the selected node
    TreeNode prior = parent.Nodes[selected.Index - 1];

    if (parent != prior)
    {
        treeViewFilter.Nodes.Remove(selected);
        prior.Nodes.Add(selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does the trick! I'll modify it a bit so i can move to the left as well.Thanks a lot for your time!