# Excel Treeview Construction

Tags: excel, treeview, vba

Using the code shown at the bottom I and able to load the Treeview for a hierarchy as shown below, this represents the sequence in which material is consumed to ultimately make Item A.

[image]

Within the Treeview I would like to show that material is consumed at different operation numbers as shown below in the left hand table to produce the below Treeview. Is it possible to achieve this without constructing a new hierarchy as shown below right.

[image]

```
Sub LoadTreeView()
Dim rNodeNames As Range, rNodeName As Range, nodX As Object

Sheet2.OLEObjects("TreeView1").Object.Nodes.Clear


Set rNodeNames = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each rNodeName In rNodeNames
    With Sheet2.OLEObjects("TreeView1").Object.Nodes
        If rNodeName.Value = "L.1" Then
            Set nodX = .Add(, , "L.1", rNodeName.Offset(, 1).Value)
        Else
            Set nodX = .Add(Left(rNodeName.Value, -1 + InStrRev(rNodeName.Value, ".")), tvwChild, rNodeName, rNodeName.Offset(, 1).Value)
        End If
        nodX.Expanded = True
   End With
Next rNodeName
End Sub
```

Comment: One way or another, you're going to have to tell it what you want where.  If the data source isn't originally Excel, it may be easiest to load and parse the data directly from the source, and add your additional levels programmatically.  Perhaps you can get some ideas from Chip Pearson's treeview example.  Note that, at no point in his example, is the data housed in a worksheet.  (If you get errors while running it, it could be poermissions-related so pick your desktop or another folder on which you have full permissions.)

Comment: ...Also there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42347051/8112776) about inserting levels.